# Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread

Tags: java, android, twitter, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to connect my app via oauth with Twitter.
I created an OAuthBaseClient with all the important information:

```
public static final Class<? extends Api> REST_API_CLASS = TwitterApi.class; 
public static final String REST_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/";
public static final String REST_CONSUMER_KEY = "consumer_key"                            public static final String REST_CONSUMER_SECRET = "consumer_secret";
public static final String REST_CALLBACK_URL = "oauth://mytwitterapp";`
```

and a constructor:

```
public RestClient(Context context) {
    super(context, REST_API_CLASS, REST_URL, REST_CONSUMER_KEY, REST_CONSUMER_SECRET, REST_CALLBACK_URL);
}
```

Now when I call the `getClient().connect();` on the OAuthLoginActionBarActivity it opens the login screen but when I press authenticate it wants to redirect me to my app, but all it does is display the loading screen:

[Loading screen sample picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIpnt.png)

and the LogCat spams this over and over:

> org.chromium.webview_shell W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread

here is my manifest:

```
`<activity
        android:name=".Twitter.TwitterLoginActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Translucent">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="com.media.cluster.cluster"
                android:scheme="com.media.cluster.cluster" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>`
```

Comment: and where is your AndroidManifest.xml ??